# How to give information on the performance of multiple answers

Tags: discussion

I found a question that was relevant for me, with quite many answers. Differences in performance are important, and I think it would be nice for others to know the results of my trials (I tested all answers for performance).

I was just wondering which would be the best way to do this. Should I write another answer? Write a comment in the question? I'm not sure this qualifies as an answer, but a comment has little visibility and is poorly formatted.

Comment: Another option to consider is writing a new _question_ about the differences, and (self-)answering it.

Comment: That hadn't even crossed my mind!

Comment: Agree with @francescalus here. I do this on occasion, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259580/replace-values-in-a-pandas-series-via-dictionary-efficiently) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020764/efficiently-return-the-index-of-the-first-value-satisfying-condition-in-array). For clarity, I'm not linking to my own self-answered questions for self-promotion, these are just examples I can quickly access.

Comment: Posting and answering your own questions on Stack Overflow is allowed, and is appreciated. Just make sure that you still ask a well formulated question, meeting the expectations of a "normal" question (sample information, expected behaviour, an MRE, etc), and then provide a well formulated answer as well. [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Thank you all. I think that is what I am going to do, then. I will ask a question citing the other one but focusing on performance and then provide an answer with the benchmarks and other useful practical information.

Comment: I don't want to take advantage of the help I've been given! On the other hand I don't know if people care about this in meta...

Comment: If the question helped you, then up-vote it. That's how we say thanks on Stack Overflow (SO). As for adding an answer, I think it might depend on the question in question.